# How do I send Phishing Protection API key over gRPC?

Tags: java, rest, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to use Google Phishing Protection API over gRPC, everything seems straight-forward looking [here](https://cloud.google.com/phishing-protection/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.phishingprotection.v1beta1), but comparing to [here](https://cloud.google.com/phishing-protection/docs/quickstart-submission-api?#request) you can see that using REST you can send a request without authenticating or some-such, rather you can pass an API key as a query param.

I tested the REST option and it works for me, but trying to use the gRPC option I get failures while trying to authenticate, which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of the REST `key` query parameter in gRPC is the `x-goog-api-key` metadata. The API to add that metadata key will vary by language.

When using Java with the googleapi client (which you should be using), you can use:

```
PhishingProtectionServiceV1Beta1Client.create(
    PhishingProtectionServiceV1Beta1Settings.newBuilder()
      .setCredentialsProvider(new NoCredentialsProvider())
      .setHeaderProvider(PhishingProtectionServiceV1Beta1Settings.defaultApiClientHeaderProviderBuilder()
          .setApiClientHeaderKey(yourApiKey)
          .build())
      .build());
```

In "plain" grpc it would look more like:

```
import io.grpc.Metadata;

private static final Metadata.Key<String> API_KEY
    = Metadata.Key.of("x-goog-api-key", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);

Metadata apiKeyMetadata = new Metadata();
apiKeyMetadata.put(API_KEY, yourApiKey);
stub = stub.withInterceptors(MetadataUtils.newAttachHeadersInterceptor(apiKeyMetadata));
```

Comment: Updated answer to include Java example.

Comment: Thanks. tested the client version, but it still throws: `java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available.`

Comment: @orirab, looks like you can do `clientSettingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(new NoCredentialsProvider())` to use no authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about gRPC it is understandable that you are required to authenticate. It is necessary for quota